# how to escape special character '?' while inserting into memsql

Tags: json, regex, mule, special-characters, singlestore

I am trying to insert JSON payload into `memsql` JSON type column but it is failing due to the following reason.
My JSON content having `'?'` character.
I tried to escape `'?'` by using the following ways, but it doesn't worked for me.

The Exception i am getting is:

```
Root Exception stack trace:
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0
```

Ex payload: "question mark content?"

```
1. #[org.mule.util.StringUtils.replace(payload,"?","\\?")]
```

Result: "question mark content\?"

```
2. #[org.mule.util.StringUtils.replace(payload,"?","\?")]
```

Result: not allowed to use the above expression

If i use the payload "question mark content" then it is inserted successfully.

Please help me how can I escape `'?'` in my JSON content while saving it into `memsql`?

Comment: In theory I don't see anything wrong with your code, can you output the line after it's replaced to ensure that there's no other special characters that are being  inserted.   Can you update your question with the exact error / string that's generating it?

Comment: @A_Elric I have updated the question with Error and results for the above expressions, please look at it.

Answer (score 0):

'\?' itself is an  escape sequence, so achive this you have to use "\\?" which produce "\?" which should work with memsql.

```
#[org.mule.util.StringUtils.replace(payload,"?","\\\\?")]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @ anupambhusari I have tried the above expression . Result after the above expression is: `\\?`. But still not working.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of your exception it looks like you are calling for it to replace the payload, but you're not assigning it to anything.

Going off of the documentation at:

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.java#3457

It basically says that it's trying to replace the items in a string, and the method itself returns a string.   Based on what I can tell in the stack trace, it seems as though you are passing a null or uninitialized variable to something that's trying to parse str[0], which is returning an array out of bounds error.

The way to correct this would be to do something like:

```
payload = org.mule.util.StringUtils.replace(payload,"?","\\\\?")
```

Which should replace any instance of ? with \? and re-write it to the payload variable.   That said, it sounds like payload may actually be null when you're evaluating it later in your program, which could be indicative of a larger issue.